# Generate number primes in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

Is there any way to generate a string list of the prime numbers in plain sql without using functions or procedures just a sql statement?

I have a solution with functions: [list of prime numbers](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e379cf838f340a970896c884958451a7)

For example, to generate prime number until number 10 a result would be something like:

```
lst_prime_numbers
2-3-5-7
```

My MySQL version is 5.7

Comment: Remember that sql is for the storage and retrieval of relational data, and not much else

Comment: generating a prime number  is a kind of calculation so I don't think so you will be able to do that  without any calculation or predefined function mysql

Comment: How big a list do you want?  There are a lot of prime numbers.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, that could be parameterized, for example, it could be ten, or one hundred or one thousand.

Answer (score 1):

> ... generate a string list of the prime numbers in plain sql without using functions or procedures just a sql statement ...
>
> ... generate prime number until number 10 ...
>
> My MySQL version is 5.7

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(num ORDER BY num SEPARATOR '-') primes
FROM ( SELECT t1.num
       FROM ( SELECT 2 num UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) t1
       JOIN ( SELECT 2 num UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) t2
       -- WHERE t1.num <= 10
       GROUP BY t1.num
       HAVING 1 = SUM((t1.num MOD t2.num) = 0)
     ) subquery
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=df0315ea3213530123394933d22d09a2)

You need to generate (or find somewhere - uncomment and adjust WHERE in this case) the numbers list from 2 to upper limit or more. You may use some service table with such data if exists, or use some system table with such data (for example, `mysql.help_keyword` contains ~700 natural numbers).

Remember - this is cartesian, which will be extremely expensive (and hence long) on large upper limit.